# Check tar file for errors

Tags: tar, bzip2

If there any way to see if there is a problem with the `.tar.bz2` file? As you can see, I can get a list of files, but neither `xjvf` nor `xzvf` works in this case.

```
$ tar tf pytorch.20210702.tar.bz2  | head -n 5
pytorch/
pytorch/BUILD.bazel
pytorch/requirements-flake8.txt
pytorch/NOTICE
pytorch/WORKSPACE

$ tar xjvf pytorch.20210702.tar.bz2
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ tar xzvf pytorch.20210702.tar.bz2    
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file`

This tells you the file is not compressed with bzip2. Therefore, the `.bz2` extension is misleading and `tar`'s `-j` option should not be used.

> `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

This tells you the file is not compressed with gzip. Therefore, `tar`'s `-z` option should not be used.

If you want to know the compression method, and thus know what `tar` option to use, you can use the `file` command:

```
file pytorch.20210702.tar.bz2
```

That said, your first attempt with `tar tf` seems to work so why not consider that your tar file is not compressed at all?

Even if it was compressed, nowadays `tar` uses auto-detection to guess the compression method and this would likely work here.

Just try:

```
$ tar xvf pytorch.20210702.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`file filename`

to find out what the real compressor is. Then you `man compressor` to find out how to verify the file integrity, normally it's the `-t` switch, i.e. `xz -t` or `bzip2 -t`.